# Help identify part: Schottky diode

Tags: identification, schottky

I have an electronic part with a marking mbr10100, I know it is a Schottky diode for 10 A, 100 V. The thing is, it looks like it has two diodes inside. At least it shows so when I test it with a multimeter. My question is - does it have tolerance of 10 A for each in the pair or will it tolerate this voltage and current when I connect them in parallel? I was not able to find a datasheet for my specific sample.

Comment: it's a Vishay part number. For me, that datasheet is the first result Google gives me for mbr10100, so I'm sure you can extend your own research a bit.

Comment: if you are speaking about this https://www.vishay.com/docs/89193/mbr10100.pdf - it is about single diode in the package. in my case it has two inside. please read question carefully.

Comment: How do you *know* it's got two diodes? I trust a device marking more than a measurement that I don't even know how it took place (no offense, but it's more likely)

Comment: it has three distinct pins, if i connect common clamp on middle and positive clamp on any other it shows it is quite ordinary schottky diode. on any side. if i test 1 and 3 pin it does not show any connection, ie infinity. multimeter is dt-830b, diode test.

Comment: OK; you need to add that to your question! Up to know I assumed hat this was effectively a two-port device with a measurement that showed two antiparallel diodes (and that can be explained by diode breakdown).

Comment: Surely you can check the datasheet? It will be the first PDF when searching for mbr10100 dual diode.

Comment: found it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasheet says it is 10A per package so 5A per diode.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the rectifier specification for the dual pair Schottky
https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/427/mbr1090c-1768506.pdf

NB. The spec describes both variants MBR1090CT-E3 and MBR10100CT-E3.